# Display JSON as HTML

Tags: html, json

Any recommendations on how to embed JSON in an HTML page with the JSON formatted in a human readable style? For example, when you view XML in a browser, most browsers display the XML formatted (indented, proper line breaks, etc). I'd like the same end result for JSON.

Color syntax highlighting would be a bonus.

Thanks

Comment: http://tohtml.com/javaProperties/ worked nicely for me; it makes the style "inline"; very helpful for simple copy-and-paste into something else.

Comment: Check out my library http://azimi.me/json-formatter-js/

Comment: Unbelievable that this useful question was closed.

Answer (score 195):

You can use the JSON.stringify function with unformatted JSON. It outputs it in a formatted way.

```
JSON.stringify({ foo: "sample", bar: "sample" }, null, 4)
```

This turns

```
{ "foo": "sample", "bar": "sample" }
```

into

```
 {
     "foo": "sample", 
     "bar": "sample" 
 }
```

Now the data is a readable format you can use the [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) script as suggested by @A. Levy to colour code it.

It is worth adding that [IE7 and older browsers do not support the JSON.stringify method](http://caniuse.com/json).

Comment: For browsers which do not support JSON.stringify (let's just come out and say it, old IE) there's an excellent polyfill you can use to get the functionality (http://www.json.org/js.html). Just include that and you'll be covered pretty much everywhere.

Comment: another trick is if you put a <br> instead of the indent field (4), you'll get nice line breaks

Comment: best answer, do the job and not need to include third party library.

Comment: I used this to great effect for a use case where the human formatted JSON had to be displayed in an HTML <textarea> element. Seemed to do the job just great.

Comment: It not worked for me. Last i found a solution. Which may be solve your problem. Here you go : http://www.codematrics.com/how-to-display-json-data-in-format/

Comment: Put this in <pre. and you're set, at least for debugging purposes, when you can't use console.log()

Comment: it's for Laravel, Codeigniter
Html: `<pre class="jsonPre"></pre>`
Return the JSON value from the controller as like as
From controller: 
**return json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);**
In script:
`<script>
$('.jsonPre').html(result);
</script>`

result will be
`{
"url": "uuyuyjhhjm",
"logo": null,
"name": null,
"@type": "",
"@context": ""
}`

Answer (score 146):

If you are deliberately displaying it for the end user, wrap the JSON text in `<PRE>` and `<CODE>` tags, e.g.:

```
<html>
<body>
<pre>
<code>
[
    {
        color: "red",
        value: "#f00"
    },
    {
        color: "green",
        value: "#0f0"
    },
    {
        color: "blue",
        value: "#00f"
    },
    {
        color: "cyan",
        value: "#0ff"
    },
    {
        color: "magenta",
        value: "#f0f"
    },
    {
        color: "yellow",
        value: "#ff0"
    },
    {
        color: "black",
        value: "#000"
    }
]

</code>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Otherwise I would use [JSON Viewer](https://web.archive.org/web/20090223053830/http://www.codeplex.com/JsonViewer).

Comment: and what if the string is all in one line? how does he make it nicely formatted like that?

Comment: You rock.  This is the simplest answer to what has been a very complex question -- how to pretty-print python json in html.  thank you.

Comment: Don't know how this doesn't have more upvotes. Simple, easy solution.

Comment: @geowa4, `JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, '  ')` will beautify it with 2 spaces. I know this is late but thought this tip will be helpful.

Comment: firefox warns with : The site ahead may contain harmful programs when you enter to codeplex.com

Comment: This way it works for me in ReactJs app. `<pre><span>{JSON.stringify(data, null, ' ')}</span></pre>`

Answer (score 68):

For the syntax highlighting, use [code prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify). I believe this is what StackOverflow uses for its code highlighting.

1. Wrap your formatted JSON in code blocks and give them the "prettyprint" class.
2. Include prettify.js in your page.
3. Make sure your document's body tag calls `prettyPrint()` when it loads

You will have syntax highlighted JSON in the format you have laid out in your page. See [here for an example](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/examples/quine.html). So if you had a code block like this:

```
<code class="prettyprint">
    var jsonObj = {
        "height" : 6.2,
        "width" : 7.3,
        "length" : 9.1,
        "color" : {
            "r" : 255,
            "g" : 200,
            "b" : 10
        }
    }
</code>
```

It would look like this:

```
var jsonObj = {
    "height" : 6.2,
    "width" : 7.3,
    "length" : 9.1,
    "color" : {
        "r" : 255,
        "g" : 200,
        "b" : 10
    }
}
```

This doesn't help with the indenting, but the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8294549/33) seem to be addressing that.

Comment: Now that all Google Code repositories are frozen we should be pointing new users directly to the new GitHub repo: [https://github.com/google/code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)

Comment: How can you get this to work within AJAX return? The code isn't there at body load, but only after ajax call.

Comment: @toddmo you should be able to follow my 3 steps in the response handler function for the AJAX return. So the handler will call prettyPrint instead of the body onLoad method. I expect that should work.

Comment: Janus Troelsen's answer fell in and just worked, so I went with that. You should check it out for PHP->HTML, so easy.

Answer (score 41):

I think you meant something like this:
[JSON Visualization](http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm)

Don't know if you might use it, but you might ask the author.

Comment: Unreal! Great! I dont know what to say... thank you so much

Comment: Really a nice tool!

Answer (score 30):

something like this ??

pretty-json

https://github.com/warfares/pretty-json

live sample:

http://warfares.github.io/pretty-json/

Comment: @PM2Ring links are working.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a light-weight solution, doing only what OP asked, including highlighting but nothing else: [How can I pretty-print JSON using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/json-pretty-print-using-javascript)

Comment: a superior function, and not just for me, if all you want to do is PHP -> HTML, and here's why: It's very lightweight, way more simple than Google to use, way smaller, and doesn't require trusting a mega company. You can actually look at the code and understand it.

Answer (score 3):

Could use JSON2HTML to transform it to nicely formatted HTML list .. may be a little more powerful than you really need though

http://json2html.com

Comment: sorry looks like the jquery plug-in site is gone bye-bye .. try http://json2html.com

Comment: try mine: https://github.com/viscocent/JSON2HTML for simpler problems

Comment: figured I'd update this with the visualizer tool http://visualizer.json2html.com

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to do this from a debugging standpoint, you can use a Firefox plugin such as [JSONovich](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10122) to view the JSON content.

The new version of Firefox that is currently in beta is slated to natively support this (much like XML)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a javasript tool that will convert JSON to XML and vice versa, which should enhance its readability.  You could then create a style sheet to color it or do a complete transform to HTML.

http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is going to be using your back-end language's tools for this. What language are you using? For Ruby, try [json_printer](http://github.com/techcrunch/json_printer/tree/master).

Answer (score 0):

**[SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/%20SyntaxHighlighter)** is a fully functional self-contained code syntax highlighter developed in JavaScript. To get an idea of what SyntaxHighlighter is capable of, have a look at the [demo](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo) page.

Answer (score -3):

First take the JSON string and make [real objects](http://json.org/) out of it.  Loop though all of the properties of the object, placing the items in an unordered list.  Every time you get to a new object, make a new list.