# How do I view this in an easy format to read? (JSON)

Tags: python, xml, json, http, twitter

https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=doug

How do I read this like VIEW SOURCE, so that I know what I'm looking at?
Is there a website that can prettify it for me?

BTW, I use python

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883977/display-json-as-html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-to-pretty-print-json-script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse it, then use [`pprint`](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html):

```
data = json.load(...)
pprint.pprint(data)
```

Comment: Or, more JSON-friendly, `print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use something like [http://hurl.it](http://hurl.it/hurls/0c2d071eff63d0006a3f056f6f095e02afe25f74/549c11edea1f99d95db0edc38b1ef6f6fea9091b).

Comment: Here is a list of tools similar to hurl : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12637452/363573

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use [JSONView](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10869) for Firefox, which does a good job formatting and colour-highlighting JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Insert a carriage return after every comma with your favorite search and replace utility. If you know Python then you shouldn't have any trouble getting it even prettier than that.