# display json data using xhrget (DOJO)

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am unable to figure out what is the problem with displaying json data..below is the code

```
var xhrGet1 = dojo.xhrGet({
       url: "Page/",
       handleAs: "json",
       handle: function(response)
       {
       dojo.byId('json-data').innerHTML = response.questions[0];
       }
       });
```

Html

```
<div id='json-data'></div>
```

And my json file looks like this

```
 {
        "Info": {
            "PURPOSE": "....  ",
            },
        "questions": [
            {
                "ID": 1,
                "Question": "User ID",
                "Information": "",

            }, {
                "ID": 2,
                "Question": "Name",
                "Information": "",

            }
        ],
```

so on...any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property handleAs : "json" in your xhr call makes the incoming json automatically eval'ed to javascript objects. So, you have to convert your javascript object back to string using JSON.stringify.
e.g. :

```
dojo.byId('json-data').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response.questions[0]);
```

You can also use [dojo.toJson](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/toJson.html#dojo-tojson) for the same purpose. It uses json.stringify but has the benefit of having a second argument ("prettyprint"), allowing you to pretty-print out of the box, like this :

```
dojo.byId('json-data').innerHTML = dojo.toJson(response.questions[0], true);
```

Comment: You're welcome... if any solution is what you are looking for, you may consider accepting it by ticking the tick sign just below the answer score...

Answer (score 0):

wrap  your JSON with PRE and CODE tags.

So:

```
dojo.byId('json-data').innerHTML = "<pre>code>" + response.questions[0] + "</code></pre>";
```

Also see: [Display JSON as HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883977/display-json-as-html) for some libraries that can help you pretty-format your JSON when rendering in the browser