# laravel print json without converting to htmlentities

Tags: php, json, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

Hi I am new to templates and laravel.

I have changed the laravel delimiters to [[]] and [[[]]] using

```
Blade::setContentTags("[[", "]]");
Blade::setEscapedContentTags("[[[", "]]]");
```

Now I want to pass the json to a javascript variable like

```
var somevariable = [[json_encode($variableFromController)]];
```

but this converts the json string to html entities like

```
{&quot;index&quot;:200}
```

I searched and Found that `{{!!json_encode($variableFromController)!!}}` should work but doing this in my system like `[[!!json_encode($variableFromController)!!]]` does not makes any impact.

I Know I can do something like `<?php echo json_encode($variableFromController) ?>` but this is the last thing I want to try. is there any laravel specific thing I can do?

Answer (score 1):

at first `Blade::setContentTags("[[", "]]");` means that replace `{!!` with `[[`. and `Blade::setEscapedContentTags("[[[", "]]]");` is replacing `{{` with `[[[`.

so for your condition `[[ json_encode($variableFromController) ]]` is the equivalent for `{!! json_encode($variableFromController) !!}`

Comment: Okay but when I write [[ json_encode($variableFromController) ]] it prints string `{&quot;index&quot;:200}` and not `{"index":200}` how can I print the plane string without getting html entities relaced.

Comment: I think it's nothing to do with laravel. it's html. in my case for testing I was using `<pre> //JSON content </pre>` but if you want other method I think `JSON.stringify` is what solves your case. look at: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195530/how-to-display-raw-json-data-on-a-html-page)