# Creating HTML element from javascript object from JSON

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax

I am writing java servlet using tomcat as servlet container.

I need a client to create an ajax-request and get json object as response.

After that client construct a HTMLElement from this json object (parsing it to js object first).

The question: is there a way to have a complete element right after parsing a json without manually setting attribute to attribute (like, HTMLElement.Property = Parsed_Json.Property)?

Because if I need to set all this manually, then I need to know what type of element I get (and use one field in JSON as tagName). But this will require something like

```
var button = document.createElement(Parsed_Json.ElementTag);
```

And then a big "if" block to realize which properties I need to set.

Maybe I can replicate the structure of a complete object in json so it will be usable right after

```
var HTMLElement = Json.parse(json_object);
```

and I will be able to do just a

```
body.appendChild(HTMLElement);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create HTML table from JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684201/create-html-table-from-javascript-object)

Comment: This [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14197981/1502615) should help you in displaying JSON content on HTML.