# Pretty Json object in html

Tags: html, angular

How do I pretty print JSON object in html? I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883977/display-json-as-html)  but not working. Please help me what I need to do to achieve this. I tried using `json` pipe:

```
<div class="box box-default">                     
    <pre>{{placeDetail |json}}</pre>                  
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like handlebars template

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/pretty-print-json-using-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can try with `|json`

```
<div class="box box-default">
    <code>
        <pre>{{placeDetail |json}}</pre>
    </code>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

For native JS: : `<script>document.write(JSON.stringfiy(placeDetail )</script>`
For angular you need to add the `<code>` tag

#### Angular:

```html
<code>
    <pre>{{placeDetail |json}}</pre>
</code>
```

#### Native JS:

```html
<div class="box box-default">
    <pre><script>document.write(JSON.stringify(placeDetail))</script></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated the answer accordinally

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 solution:

https://plnkr.co/edit/msa5JDjPUxGMFcHptTu8?p=preview

javascript solution:

```js
var placeDetail = {
    'a': {
        'b': 1,
        'c': 2
    },
    'd': 3
}; 
document.getElementById("json-result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(placeDetail, undefined, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="json-result">
</pre>
```

Comment: @ShaileshLadumor I added plunker link in answer check it

Comment: The javascript solution should use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` in order to prevent [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) attacks.