# Formatting a string to JSON Object to disply in HTML In a textarea w/ [(ngModel)]

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, format

I have a string json object that I am trying to format and display in the html. I have tried using `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` but the typeof is still showing as a string and it is displaying in a straight line instead of formatting . I also tried `<pre> {{formatJson | json}}</pre>` and still no success.

```
formatJSON: string  = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":{"d":3, "e":4}}'

ngOnInit() {
  var test = json.parse(this.formatJSON);
  console.log(typeof test); //string
  this.formatJSON = JSON.stringify(test, null, "   ")

}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div>
  <textarea [(ngModel)]="formatJSON" class="text-area" cols="200" rows="10">
       {{formatJSON}}
  </textarea>
</div>


<!-- <pre>{{formatJSON | json}}</pre> -->
```

Desired Output:

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 pipe that transforms JSON object to pretty-printed JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308420/angular-2-pipe-that-transforms-json-object-to-pretty-printed-json)

Comment: Your string isn't valid JSON.

Comment: JSON is basically a map from `string` to `any`. But in your case, your fields are not string which makes your JSON invalid.

Comment: What do you mean my fields are not string? and what would be the solution then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pretty Json object in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253208/pretty-json-object-in-html)

Comment: I tried out the pretty json custom pipe but it didn't work it looks like I have to do some type of innerHTML or something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var data = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":{"d":3,"e":4}}


document.getElementById("json-textArea").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
```

```css
textarea { 

width:100px;
height: 150px;

}
```

```html
<textarea id="json-textArea"></textarea>
```

check this stackblitz for the [angular version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lfw6da?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html): In Angular you just need to run your JSON data through `json` pipe and you will be fine.

Comment: where is the css info for  json-container Im using angular with material design

Comment: you don't need it.. it's just a sample class name. Your `<code>` tag should take care of it.

Comment: it still displyed it in one  line and I also need it in a textarea tag

Comment: Make sure the JSON output is in a <pre> tag. Check  his: http://jsfiddle.net/K83cK/

Comment: so it can't be in a textarea tag

Comment: Updated my answer.. please check

Comment: it displayed as [OBJECT, OBJECT]

Comment: did you use `<textarea>{{data | json}}</textarea>` check the stackblitz link which is shared in answer.

Comment: oh ok it was becasue I was suing ngModel. I can't have [(ngmode)]?

Comment: You should not use `pipe` with two way data-binding, if you really want to use it with `ngModel`, you should consider one way data binding with `ngModelChange`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191032/discussion-between-nircraft-and-flash).

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. Update your JSON string like below

```
formatJSON = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": {
        "d": 3,
        "e": 4
    }
}
```

You can apply angular pipe on formatJSON in your html like this `{{formatJSON | json}}`.

Comment: well the real issue is its coming back from the server as a string object? So how would I format it in a text area

Comment: yeah and formateed. and really it's coming back from the server as a string so I don't know it I can just remove the quotes.

Comment: First your server should send the proper json. If not then you won't be able to format it. Once you have a correct JSON you can use angular pipe to format it in HTML or in your component.

Comment: Thanks when you say proper JSON you mean without quotes?

Comment: yes. What's your server side code. Is it node js api or something else.

Answer (score 1):

I have applied it in angular Dialog material like this

in ts file

```
this.response=JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(item.response_body), null, 2);
```

in html

```
<mat-dialog-content>
  <pre class="response-class"> {{data.response}}   </pre>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

in css

```
 ::ng-deep .response-class {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

It will work fine if it's a valid json, you can use pretty json to check from it 
http://jsonprettyprint.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to show json, with the json pipe behaves the same as doing `JSON.stringify(yourData)` in your code

```
<pre>{{ yourData | json }}</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing! If you find time please edit an explanation into the answer as it's recommended to [explain entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421) on StackOverflow.