# Display JSON file data in Flask HTML

Tags: python, html, json, flask

I am working on a python flask application and would like to display the data from a JSON file onto the html webpage. But when I do so, I loose the JSON structure and the result is not what I expected it to be. I would like the webpage to display the data in a expandable structure. Can I get some help with this?

**JSON Data**

```
[
   [
      {
         "Name": "Harold",
         "ID": "CX1024",
         "Job": "Sales",
         "Address": {
            "Street": "37  Philadelphia Avenue",
            "Postal Code": "84010",
            "City": "Bountiful"
         },
         "Emergency Contact": {
            "Person": "Mark",
            "Relation": "Brother",
            "Phone": "801-296-4536"
         }
      },
      {
         "Name": "James",
         "ID": "CX1120",
         "Job": "Sales",
         "Address": {
            "Street": "671  Lonely Oak Drive",
            "Postal Code": "04617",
            "City": "BROOKSVILLE"
         },
         "Emergency Contact": {
            "Person": "Stephen",
            "Relation": "Father",
            "Phone": "251-454-0515"
         }
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "Name": "Sarah",
         "ID": "RJ1020",
         "Job": "Management",
         "Address": {
            "Street": "4991  Stoney Lane",
            "Postal Code": "75081",
            "City": "Richardson"
         },
         "Emergency Contact": {
            "Person": "Curtis",
            "Relation": "Husband",
            "Phone": "972-995-0475"
         }
      },
      {
         "Name": "Clarkson",
         "ID": "RJ1117",
         "Job": "Management",
         "Address": {
            "Street": "4663  Kovar Road",
            "Postal Code": "02192",
            "City": "Needham"
         },
         "Emergency Contact": {
            "Person": "Angie",
            "Relation": "Sister",
            "Phone": "508-578-0498"
         }
      }
   ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I would recommend.

Firstly, you need to "stringify" your JSON object (to get that nice formatting you have above). From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883977/display-json-as-html) answer, the way to do that is, using JavaScript:

```js
JSON.stringify({ foo: "sample", bar: "sample" }, null, 4)
```

(Note `JSON.stringify(...)` is unavailable in some versions of IE. Theoretically, you could also do this with Python and send a "raw" string... but sending JSON makes a *lot* more sense; let the frontend handle formatting.)

Next, you need the right HTML tags to render the string. You need `<pre>` to preserve the whitespace ("pre" means "preformatted") and you might want `<code>` as well.

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <pre>
   <code>
   { 
       foo: "sample", 
       bar: "sample" 
   }
   </code>
  </pre>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The JSON is a local file, will it work for that?

Comment: Sure, you'll just have to read in the JSON file and spit the data to your FE. If it's just a local file, you might be able to just directly include it on the frontend as well.