# Display var as json on page

Tags: javascript, json

I have this function within Javascript;

```
function newripple() {
  var api = new ripple.RippleAPI();
  var account = api.generateAddress();
  document.getElementById("address").value = account.address;
  document.getElementById("secret").value = account.secret;
}
```

What I would like to do is instead of assigning these values to input fields I would like to display them on the page as JSON.

My index page is very simple;

```
<h2>Ripple Wallet Generator</h2>
<p><b>Ripple Address</b></p>
<input readonly="readonly" id="address" style="width: 300px;">
<p><b>Ripple Secret</b></p>
<input readonly="readonly" id="secret" style="width: 300px;">
```

I am not very familiar with JavaScript I very much appreciate any help.

The desired result when i load the page would be something like ;

```
{"address":"VALUE","secret":"VALUE"}
```

Comment: What is the expected result? And what have you tried so far to solve this on your own? - [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: the desired result would be for the account and secret to display like json ecoded with the two values on the page instead of the values being put into the input fields; so like when i lost the page its something like {"account":"VALUE","secret":"VALUE"}

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883977/display-json-as-html

Comment: What is `account`? Is it JSON, is it an object?

Comment: @Andy its an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the [object to a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), and add the result to the page.

```js
const account = { address: '10 Albert Street', secret: 'secret' };

const div = document.querySelector('div');

div.textContent = JSON.stringify(account);
```

```html
<div />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [JSON.stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)

```
const json = '{"address":1, "secret":2}';
const obj = JSON.parse(json);
var i = JSON.stringify(obj)
console.log(i);
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a JSON object like this -

```
let json = {'address':account.address, 'secret':account.secret};
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json)
```

Now its upto you how you want to show this

Comment: i tried `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = json; ` to write it to the body but all i get is `[object Object]`

Comment: Try document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json)

Comment: You should edit your answer because at the moment it doesn't make any sense. That's not JSON.